# CSS pseudo :target element animation not working on slider

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a simple css slider that shows specific text when in the :target state. The text actually appears fine but what's happening is it's just appearing instead of sliding in. I have left:0 set on the parent and the idea being that when the slide id is selected the parent should move to left: -100%/-200%/-300% depending on the slide targeted. Hope this makes sense, markup is below.

Appreciate any advice where I have gone wrong.

```css
.slider__wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider__inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 300%;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .6s;
}

.slider__slides {
  float: left;
  width: 33.333%;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.slider__toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#slide--1 {
  background: red;
}

#slide--2 {
  background: yellow;
}

#slide--3 {
  background: green;
}

#slide--1:target~.slider__inner {
  left: 0;
  transition: all .6s;
}

#slide--2:target~.slider__inner {
  left: -100%;
  transition: all .6s;
}

#slide--3:target~.slider__inner {
  left: -200%;
  transition: all .6s;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider__wrapper">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider__inner">
      <div class="slider__slides" id="slide--1">
        slide 1
      </div>
      <div class="slider__slides" id="slide--2">
        slide 2
      </div>
      <div class="slider__slides" id="slide--3">
        slide 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slider__toggle">
    <a href="#slide--1">01</a>
    <a href="#slide--2">02</a>
    <a href="#slide--3">03</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you are targeting a **parent** element not a sibling element and this won't work

Comment: This is wrong #slide--1:target~.slider__inner in your html your don't have that structure. .slicer__inner is a parent of #slide-1 not sibling

Comment: I see where I have gone wrong here! I will have a play around with my markup and see if i can get this working correctly